# Bootstrapping to address interval censored data

Tags: survival, bootstrap, censoring, interval-censoring

I am trying to run a cox proportional hazards model on data that is interval-censored (and I guess right censored). Within this model, I believe one of my covariates' relationship should be modeled with a spline. However, I am unable to find an implementation of a cox model that allows interval censoring and splines (and maybe I want a couple of other spices to add on as well).

I am curious if I can do a poor man's job of addressing interval censoring. By that, I mean for each observation, assume that if an event did occur between a lower and upper bound, that event a uniform chance of occurring between the two points in time. With that assumption, I could implement a bootstrap routine

1. I randomly sampled the data with replacement, for each sampled
   individual (patient/entity etc..)
2. For each individual where an event did occur, sample the time of the event occurring from a uniform distribution that is bounded between the lower and upper event limits, and use that sampled time to run a regular survival analysis.
3. repeat the process 1,000 times and use estimated coefficients from the iterations to construct 95% uncertainty intervals.

Playing around with some simulations it seems like I am in the ballpark

```
library(data.table)
library(survival)
library(mgcv)
library(icenReg)
set.seed(1)
data("IR_diabetes", package = "icenReg")
IR_diabetes <- data.table( IR_diabetes)

IR_diabetes[, diff:= right-left]
IR_diabetes[, id:= factor(1:.N)]
cols <- paste0("draw_", 1:1000)
draws <- IR_diabetes[,unlist(lapply(diff, function(x) runif(1000, 0, x))), by = id]
draws <- matrix(draws[,V1], ncol = 1000, byrow = T)
draws <- data.table(draws)
colnames(draws) <- paste0("draw_", 1:1000)
IR_diabetes <- cbind(IR_diabetes, draws)

haz <- c()
for(i in paste0("draw_", 1:500)){
  
  IR_diabetes[, new:= left + IR_diabetes[,i, with=F] ] 
  index <- sample(1:nrow(IR_diabetes), nrow(IR_diabetes),replace = T)
  
  b <- mgcv::gam(as.formula(paste0("new", "~gender")),
            family=cox.ph(), data=IR_diabetes[index,])
  
  haz <- c(haz, coef(b))
}

int_reg <- ic_par(cbind(left, right) ~ gender, data = IR_diabetes)
print(summary(int_reg))
quantile(haz, c(.025, .5, .975))
```

And results from interval censoring

```
Model:  Cox PH
Dependency structure assumed: Independence
Baseline:  weibull 
Call: ic_par(formula = cbind(left, right) ~ gender, data = IR_diabetes)

           Estimate Exp(Est) Std.Error z-value       p
log_shape    1.0390   2.8260   0.02814  36.910 0.00000
log_scale    2.9360  18.8500   0.01427 205.800 0.00000
gendermale  -0.1293   0.8787   0.07773  -1.664 0.09614

final llk =  -2027.196 
Iterations =  4
```

Taking the percentiles of the bootstraps...

```
 quantile(haz, c(.025, .5, .975))
       2.5%         50%       97.5% 
-0.25164955 -0.11390303  0.03152995
```

So the approximation of the standard error from the bootstrap is 0.75 which is right about in line, and the median of the draws comes close to the estimated coef from an interval-censored model. My question is, is this approach legit?

Comment: The uniform sampling of event times within the censoring limits is imposing an assumption about event-time distributions. Is the nature of your interval censoring such that you could use discrete-time survival analysis, which is essentially just a set of logistic regressions? Also, have you tried combining tools from different software packages, for example using the restricted cubic splines for regression provided by the `rcs()` function in the R `rms` package together with `icenReg` for handling the interval censoring?